# Understanding tight bounds

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Is the big theta of log(n^(2logn)) equal to the big theta of log(n^(logn))? I need a proper justification for the answer. I tried plotting the graphs but I couldn't come to a conclusion.

Comment: The first is exactly double the second. log(a^b) = b log(a).

Comment: And log(n^(2 log n)) = log((n^(log n))²)